# should I use @csrf_protect in my django logout view along with the middleware

Tags: django, csrf

I have a custom logout view .I have added the decorators  like below

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout_then_login

@csrf_protect
@require_POST
@never_cache
def logout(request):
    nxt=request.POST.get('next')
    print 'next=',nxt
    return logout_then_login(request, nxt)
```

In my settings file I have the following middleware classes

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)
```

Since the CsrfViewMiddleware is included here,do I really need the @csrf_protect for my view?If I use both,will there be some problem/conflict?

As an aside,when I checked the [django source](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L25),I found that the decorators are applied only for the login view and not for any of the logout,login_then_logout views.Why is that?

Any help most welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Middleware gives you blanket protection on all views - adding the decorator is redundant. The Django docs recommend using the Middleware over the decorator as it provides better protection.

> Use of the decorator by itself is not recommended, since if you forget
>   to use it, you will have a security hole. The 'belt and braces'
>   strategy of using both is fine, and will incur minimal overhead.

The decorators aren't used for the views you mentioned because there is little to no risk of a session being hijacked via CSRF if a login_then_logout event is triggered and there is no security risk to a user once a session has been destroyed.

You seem to have a lot of questions regarding CSRF - might I suggest you bone up on [Django's CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/) and CSRF in [general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)?

Comment: thanks @Todd ,being a newbie to django & web dev,I am struggling to understand the technologies..I am browing thru the django source code and often get confused

Comment: @damon, I wouldn't use the source as a guide to the framework. Django's docs are among some of the best I've ever used (if not *the* best). I would definitely read the Django Tutorial on the website and supplement it with the rest of the official Django documentation.